# Select 1 object from list with LINQ based on 2 vars

Tags: c#, linq, list, select

I've been trying to solve this by reading what was on StackOverflow and the information was quiet helpful but i can't seem to implement the things i found.

I have a data List and i want to check if an entry exists in the data set that match 2 variables i provide.

```
public void SaveWaveDataFor( List<WaveData> newData )
{
    foreach(WaveData wave in newData)
    {
        //WaveData item = data.FirstOrDefault( o => o.id == wave.id );
        var item = data.Select( o => new{ wave.id, wave.waveNumber  } );
        Debug.Log( item.id );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all of the `wave` objects that match two criteria, you can use a `Where()` clause:

```
// items will be an IEnumerable<WaveData> containing the matching objects
// where id == matchId and waveNumber == matchNumber
var items = data.Where(o => o.id == matchId && o.waveNumber == matchNumber);
```

The `Select()` clause is typically used to transform the matching elements into objects of another type.

Comment: I changed Where to .FirstOrDefault and it seems to do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

The commented out line is better for this actually.

FirstOrDefault will return either the first matching item or null if no items match.

On the other hand, you could use Any() if you just want to know if an item exists.
Any(x=>x.Id == matchId) will return true only if the list contains an item with a matching Id, false otherwise.

You would do it like this:

```
public void SaveWaveDataFor( List<WaveData> newData )
{
    int waveIdToMatch = 1;
    int waveNumberToMatch = 2;
    foreach(WaveData wave in newData)
    {
        WaveData item = data.FirstOrDefault( o => o.id == waveIdToMatch && o.waveNumber == waveNumberToMatch );
        //if a match exists, item will not be a WaveData object, otherwise it will be null
        Debug.Log( item.id );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check whether entry exists or not then you can use `Any` Operator from Linq.

```
bool recordsExists = data.Any(o => o.id == matchId && o.waveNumber == matchNumber);
```